# How to aggregate XML snippets in GROUP BY operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, group-by

I'm working with some rows that contain XML snippets.

My rows in their current state look like this:

```
TeamId     Player
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  <Player><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
1   |  <Player><FirstName>Sam</FirstName><LastName>Jones</LastName></Player>
2   |  <Player><FirstName>David</FirstName><LastName>White</LastName></Player>
2   |  <Player><FirstName>James</FirstName><LastName>Black</LastName></Player>
```

With my query I'm looking to group the rows by `TeamId` and aggregate those XML snippets into a parent `<Players>` element, so the output will look like this:

```
1   | <Players>
        <Player><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
        <Player><FirstName>Sam</FirstName><LastName>Jones</LastName></Player>
      </Players>  
2   | <Players>
        <Player><FirstName>David</FirstName><LastName>White</LastName></Player>
        <Player><FirstName>James</FirstName><LastName>Black</LastName></Player>
      </Players>
```

How should I do this? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just i tried like this

```
CREATE TABLE #A
    (
    TEAMID INT,
    PLAYER XML 
    )
    INSERT INTO #A VALUES
    (1,'<PLAYER><FIRSTNAME>BOB</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>SMITH</LASTNAME></PLAYER>'),
    (1,'<PLAYER><FIRSTNAME>SAM</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>JONES</LASTNAME></PLAYER>'),
    (2,'<PLAYER><FIRSTNAME>DAVID</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>WHITE</LASTNAME></PLAYER>'),
    (2,'<PLAYER><FIRSTNAME>JAMES</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>BLACK</LASTNAME></PLAYER>')


SELECT  T.TEAMID,
        (   SELECT  TEAMID ,
                    PLAYER
            FROM    #A AS X
            WHERE X.TeamId = T.TeamId
            FOR XML PATH('PLAYER'), TYPE, ROOT('PLAYERS')

        ) AS XML_FORMAT_STRING
FROM    #A AS T
GROUP BY T.TEAMID;
```

Comment: Root('Players')

Comment: Also join condition is missing inside subquery 'WHERE X.TeamId = T.TeamId'

Comment: @KannanKandasamy  Thanks:)

Comment: That was almost exactly right - but there's an extra `<PLAYER>` element around each player - do you know how to eliminate that? Thanks for your help so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
SELECT  tbl.TeamId,
        (   SELECT Player AS [*]
            FROM   YourTable AS X
            WHERE X.TeamId = tbl.TeamId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Players')
        ) AS [*]
FROM    YourTable AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.TeamId;
```

The alias `AS [*]` tells the engine to insert the given element *as-is*. This avoids extra name levels. The empty `PATH('')` also avoids an additional name level.